# How to type sets for a given string

Tags: c#, list, recursion, set, backtracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I obtain all the possible combination of a subset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765699/how-can-i-obtain-all-the-possible-combination-of-a-subset)

I am trying to type the sets for a given string for example
"123" will give {1}{2}{3}{13}{23}{12}{123}{}
but my code gives me 1 1 
Please can Anyone tell me why and please help me to fix it 
Thanks all

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;

namespace TestAAD
{
class Program
{
    static List<string> sets = new List<string>();
    static int len = 0;

    private static void Generte_Sets(string str, int i)
    {

        sets.Add(str[i].ToString());

        if (i < len)
            Generte_Sets(str, i + 1);
        else
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sets.Count; j++)
                Console.Write(sets[j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        sets.Remove(str[i].ToString());  
        if (i < len)
            Generte_Sets(str, i + 1);
        else
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sets.Count; j++)
                Console.Write(sets[j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string set = "123";

        Generte_Sets(set, 0);
        len = set.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < sets.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sets[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please I need help to type the sets 
I need quick help 
thanks All

Comment: Why do you repeat the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778758/how-can-i-split-a-character-o

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static List<string> sets = new List<string>();
        static int len = 0;

        private static void Generte_Sets(string str, int i)
        {
            sets.Add(str[i].ToString());           

            **if (i + 1 < len)**
                Generte_Sets(str, i + 1);
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < sets.Count; j++)
                    Console.Write(sets[j]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            sets.Remove(str[i].ToString());          

            **if (i + 1 < len)**
                Generte_Sets(str, i + 1);
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < sets.Count; j++)
                    Console.Write(sets[j]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             string set = "123"; 
             **len = set.Length;**
             Generte_Sets(set, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < sets.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sets[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```