# Calculate possible combinations for SKU

Tags: c#, .net, combinations

I have this situation:

- a product with an SKU
- this product has attributes (checkboxes) who have a SKU suffix
- (imagine a product with addons)

Attributes are always in a fixed order and are not manditory. The final SKU for a product is basesku + selected attributes' suffixes.

For example a product with basesku `XXX` has 3 attributes with suffixes `A`, `B` and `C`.

Possible combinations for this product are:

```
XXX-A
XXX-A-B
XXX-A-B-C
XXX-A-C
XXX-B
XXX-B-C
XXX-C
```

Because the attributes are in a fixed order, it is never possible to have `XXX-C-B` for example.

What is the best way to calculate these SKU's?

Edit: I should have told these attributes are dynamically created. So it is not possible to have attA + "-" + attB. I need a way to dynamically generate the list of possible SKU's

Comment: Just have a Public Property SKUwSuffix and build it up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I obtain all the possible combination of a subset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765699/how-can-i-obtain-all-the-possible-combination-of-a-subset)

Comment: yes duplicate, thanks for the comment I could not find this before

Answer (score 3):

Use a `StringBuilder`

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("XXX");
if (skuACheckBox.Checked) {
    sb.Append("-A");
}
if (skuBCheckBox.Checked) {
    sb.Append("-B");
}
if (skuCCheckBox.Checked) {
    sb.Append("-C");
}
string skuWithSuffix = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the other answer is a count.
Sorry if I read the question wrong.

```
Public String SKU { get; set; }

Public bool Aattr { get: set; }
Public bool Battr { get: set; }
Public bool Cattr { get: set; }

Public String SKUwSuffix 
{
   get
   {
      string sKUwSuffix = SKU; 
      if (Aattr) sKUwSuffix += "-A";
      if (Battr) sKUwSuffix += "-B";
      if (Cattr) sKUwSuffix += "-C";
      return sKUwSuffix;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to maintain a non duplicate selected suffix attribute collection and finally  concatenate the sku by using the collection.