# Get all sub arrays of a particular length in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, subset

I want help with getting the subsets of an array in C#.
All other examples could not help me much.

I want to get all the subsets of a particular size of an array.

for example if input array is {1,2,3,4} and i want all subsets of size 3,
all the unique subsets {1,2,3},{1,2,4},{2,3,4},{1,3,4} must be returned.

I am new to C# and any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765699/how-can-i-obtain-all-the-possible-combination-of-a-subset

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952153/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-all-combinations-of-items-in-an-array

Answer (score 0):

Check this article.  This is described in detail with examples in all sorts of programming languages.  I don't feel the need to copy others solutions so I will leave this as a link for you to choose from the MANY examples which should help you

[Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment....

Since I presume the size is variable, you'll want to use recursion.  Something like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] originalList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        Stack<int> currentList = new Stack<int>();
        List<int[]> listOfSubsets = new List<int[]>();

        BuildListOfSubsets(originalList, listOfSubsets, 3, 0, currentList);
    }

    private static void BuildListOfSubsets(int[] originalList, List<int[]> listOfSubsets, int sizeOfSubsetList, int currentLevel, Stack<int> currentList)
    {
        if (currentList.Count == sizeOfSubsetList)
        {
            int[] copy = new int[sizeOfSubsetList];
            currentList.CopyTo(copy, 0);
            listOfSubsets.Add(copy);
        }
        else
            for (int ix = currentLevel; ix < originalList.Length; ix++)
            {
                currentList.Push(originalList[ix]);
                BuildListOfSubsets(originalList, listOfSubsets, sizeOfSubsetList, ix + 1, currentList);
                currentList.Pop();
            }
    }
```

The result will be in the listOfSubsets list.  See if you can find an optimization to leave the for loop early.

Comment: The question is asking SubArrays, this is returning subsets

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a LINQ solution, try this:

```cs
int[] originalList = { 1,2,1 };
var srcl = originalList.ToList();
List<List<int>> ans = Enumerable.Range(0, srcl.Count).SelectMany(start => Enumerable.Range(1, srcl.Count - start).Select(count => srcl.GetRange(start, count))).ToList();
```

If you are looking for a simpler solution, without Recursion, then this will help:

(This is a common solution to print all the subsets, to print specific scenarios, like having only subsets with length as 3, use the innermost loop)

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int length = arr.Length;

            for (int start = 0; start < length; start++)
            {
                for (int end = start; end < length; end++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{");
                    // printing the subset, use this to add any condition, 
                    // like create a array and match the length, or anything
                    for (int print = start; print <= end; print++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(arr[print]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("}");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```