# Key Value Pair List

Tags: c#, arrays, keyvaluepair

I have a list with below elements:

```
{[A,1] ; [B,0] ; [C,0] ; [D,2]; [E,0] ; [F,8]}
```

When Variable =3 -> i want the return value to be A,D

When variable =11 -> return value to be A, D, F

when 2 -> return value to be D

and so on.

```
 int sum = myList.Sum(x => x.Value)
```

how to get the corresponding Key (A,D,F)?

Comment: Have you written any code yet? Just can try looking  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) for a place to start from.

Comment: How do you pick these items? sum()?

Comment: I *think* the sum of their values must sum up to the input value

Comment: What should be returned when input is `0`. B? C? E? or `B,C and E`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel makes a good point.  If the input is always > 0 then we need to eliminate them as candidates.  If 0 is a valid input, then who is right?

Comment: @Moo-Juice So many confusion. What if list has `2,1,1,4` and input is `4` return value to be `2,1,1` or `4`?

Comment: This actually looks like enum flags question. However the values selected for the flags aren't the usual powers of two which would ensure each flag is orthogonal.

Comment: Try a dictionary https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Answer (score 106):

Using one of the *subsets* method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765699/how-can-i-obtain-all-the-possible-combination-of-a-subset)

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>() { 
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("A", 1),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B", 0),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("C", 0),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("D", 2),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("E", 8),
};

int input = 11;
var items = SubSets(list).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Sum(y => y.Value)==input);
```

---

**EDIT**

a full console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>() { 
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("A", 1),
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B", 2),
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("C", 3),
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("D", 4),
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("E", 5),
                new KeyValuePair<string, int>("F", 6),
            };

            int input = 12;
            var alternatives = list.SubSets().Where(x => x.Sum(y => y.Value) == input);

            foreach (var res in alternatives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", res.Select(x => x.Key)));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("END");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class Extenions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SubSets<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        {
            List<T> list = enumerable.ToList();
            ulong upper = (ulong)1 << list.Count;

            for (ulong i = 0; i < upper; i++)
            {
                List<T> l = new List<T>(list.Count);
                for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(ulong) * 8; j++)
                {
                    if (((ulong)1 << j) >= upper) break;

                    if (((i >> j) & 1) == 1)
                    {
                        l.Add(list[j]);
                    }
                }

                yield return l;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks 14V - but what is subsets here ? - doesnt seem to come up in visual studio.

Comment: @user2778395 I posted its link in the answer. I used for ex, L.B's version.